# Swift seemingly strange behavior in `init` while setting up UI

Tags: ios, swift

In the `required init` of my `UIView`inheriting class, I'm trying to initialize a member variable and then set up the view's subviews with the data from the member variable (i.e. text). Consider the following pseudo-code which successfully loads the UI with the variable's data:

```
class Event {
    var title: String?
}

class A: UIView {

    let event: Event! {
        didSet {
            self.title_label.text = event.title
        }
    }

    required init(event: Event) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect(...))
        self.setupUI(with: event)
    }

    func setupUI(with event: Event) {
        self.event = event
        self.addSubview(title_label)
        self.constrainTitleLabel()
    }

    let title_label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        ...
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    ...
}
```

However, if I move the initialization of `event` from the function to `init`, the UI no longer displays the variable's data:

```
class A: UIView {

    let event: Event! {
        didSet {
            self.title_label.text = event.title
        }
    }

    required init(event: Event) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect(...))
        self.event = event
        self.setupUI(with: event)
    }

    func setupUI(with event: Event) {
        self.addSubview(title_label)
        self.constrainTitleLabel()
    }

    let title_label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        ...
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    ...
}
```

Why doesn't the second way set `title_label.text` properly? I'm pretty sure this is sufficiently close to my own code, but if there isn't actually a problem with this code then I've missed something that I've done. Thanks.

Comment: Where is `title_label` created? This is the problem when you don't share *actual code*, bits are missing

Comment: I'll add it if that will help

Comment: You still haven't shown where you actually *allocate* `title_label`; my suspicion is that you are doing so after you have already set `event`, so the setter doesn't set the label

Comment: @Paulw11 sorry I actually had to leave my computer.

Comment: @Paulw11 Updated, finally.

Comment: It seems to me that your required init() ... you should be setting 'event' before the call to super() (the 2 phase initialization - your local properties should be assigned before calling super).

Comment: Okay, but why does the first way work when I still initialize `event` after `super.init`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`didSet` observers are not called for values set from `init`.

> The willSet and didSet observers of superclass properties are called when a property is set in a subclass initializer, after the superclass initializer has been called. They are not called while a class is setting its own properties, before the superclass initializer has been called.

(from [Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html)).

Unfortunately, the documentation is not completely correct. See bug [SR-1118](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1118). The observers are never called when the value is set from `init`.

Comment: So the first way I showed works because `self.event = event` isn't _directly_ called inside `init` but rather in a function call, whereas in the second way, it was called inside `init`? And `didSet` gets called for that function but not for `init`?

Comment: @ArchieGertsman Exactly. You can verify simply by putting a `print` in `didSet`.